# Absorb/Filter mercury energy spikes from fluorescent lights?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation

Fluorescent lights feature strong radiation at certain wavelengths due to the presence of mercury (image on the right):

[image]

Is there a way to create a filter that will selectively absorb these spikes, meaning the ones at ~500nm and ~415nm, while allowing energy at other wavelengths to pass through?

Is there a standard resource that tells the absorption spectra for different materials?

Comment: First, why do you need to do so? The application matters for a reasonable answer.

Comment: what peak at 500 nm?  Do you mean 545nm?

Comment: Absorbing the peaks would reduce the energy efficiency making it closer to incandescent.  The only remaining advantage of mergury over halogen would be a longer life.